# How to use preprocessor macro in header to name specific part of an array

Tags: c, gcc

I have an array of settings read from an external device like this and I want to use define to improve usability.

**Code**

In settings.h :

```
#define LEN_SETTINGS 38 //Number of settings to read

#define MY_FIRST_SETTING    settings[0]
#define MY_SECOND_SETTING   settings[1]
...
```

In settings.c :

```
uint8_t settings[LEN_SETTINGS]; //Array with all settings updated by SPI
```

**Goal**

My goal is to use to update the settings array in a file and use the values in other file that include "settings.h" and `extern uint8_t settings[LEN_SETTING]`. For performance reason, I've choosen to not split the array in as much variables (target is a low power MCU).

**The error**

'settings' undeclared (first use in this function)  settings.h line X. "setting" is not declared in header so I understand why it give me an error but can't find a solution.

**Other infos**

I use ISO C99, no specific option I'm aware of.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. If you declare (the `extern` declaration you claim to have) then you should not be getting such an error. Do you remember to `#include` the header file where you have the declaration of the array?

Comment: Which line of the header is that error related to? What is content of that line. The header content you show us, cannot cause such an error as `settings` is not used there. Do you define functions in your header?

Comment: `For performance reason, I've choosen to not split the array in as much variables` That sounds odd. Is there some assumption that not-array variables are "slower" when compared with arrays? Why? `"setting" is not declared in header` Sure it isn't, you did `extern uint8_t settings[LEN_SETTING]` while there is `LEN_SETTINGS` not `LEN_SETTING`.

Comment: I had the extern declaration in the source file of the user code, not in my settings.h hence the problem.


The line related to error was the line of "#define MY_FIRST_SETTING    settings[0]" and similar declaration.


The performance reason is just that the SPI function to read the external device fill an array. If I want to read settings one by one the transfer is a lot slower (since using a DMA for +/- 38 bytes is better than 38 DMA transfer for one byte)

Comment: The line holding macro definition does not cause that error. Only when that macro is actually used, you might get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line in your header file.

```
extern uint8_t settings[LEN_SETTING];
```

or for some compilers,

```
extern uint8_t settings[];
```

Answer (score 0):

A correct way to design the program would be to drop spaghetti-programming `extern` in favour for private encapsulation. Then drop all mysterious macros as well. Instead do something like this:

settings.h

```
typedef enum
{
  SETTING_FIRST,
  SETTING_SECOND,
  ...
  SETTINGS_N 

} setting_t;

uint8_t setting_get (setting_t setting);
```

settings.c

```
#include "settings.h"

static uint8_t settings [SETTINGS_N];

uint8_t setting_get (setting_t setting)
{
  return settings [setting];
}
```

caller.c

```
#include "settings.h"

uint8_t data = setting_get(SETTING_FIRST);
```

This is fast enough for the overwhelming majority of all embedded system use-cases. If you have extreme requirements you could inline the getter function, sacrificing proper design for a tiny bit of performance.

Note however that none of the above (nor the extern spaghetti version) make much sense if this is a buffer filled up directly from SPI. In that case you have to handle re-entrancy and real-time requirements:

- What happens when SPI is receiving data, is it handled by polling, interrupts or DMA?
- How does that data make it inside the array?
- How do you handle the re-entrancy case when the driver and the caller need to use the buffer at once?
- Which variables need to be `volatile` because they are shared with an ISR or used as DMA buffer?

And so on. You need to decide these things way before you write higher layer application logic.